# Applescript - get the coordinates of an element

Tags: macos, applescript, mouseevent, coordinates

I need to get the coordinates {X,Y} of an element in order to generate a click event on it (I can't do that by using "click" since System Events has problem doing that and returns: "missing value"). I'll use these coordinates to pass them to a command line tool that simulates a mouse click.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you get the properties of the ui element? I think you can even if you can't actually click it. One of the properties should be "position" and another will be "size". Those 2 things should help you find the screen coordinates so you can click the element.

For example try this and look at the properties...

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        properties of UI element 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

So if I wanted to know the coordinates of the middle of that element so you can click it this would give you the x and y coordinates of where to click...

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        tell UI element 1 of window 1
            set p to position
            set s to size
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

set xCoordinate to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) / 2
set yCoordinate to (item 2 of p) + (item 2 of s) / 2
return {p, s, xCoordinate, yCoordinate}
```